# Surjective of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

How to show that the complex function $f(z) = z + e^z$ is surjective on C?

I know $f= e^z$ is not injective only. How can I use it in the above problem?

Comment: By Picard, you know that it omits *at most* one point.

Comment: What kind of machinery can you throw at it?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that $f(z)=z+e^z$ omits some value $a\in\mathbb{C}$, then $f(z)$ omits also $a\pm 2\pi i$ since $f(z+2\pi i)=f(z)+2\pi i$. Since any entire function may omit at most one value by Picard's little theorem, $f(z)$ is surjective.